# Redirect to mobile application with mail link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a mobile application with React native. In my web application, I am sending an e-mail to the user for the mail verification process. I direct the user to the account creation page with the button in the HTML mail template. If the user is accessing from the phone and the mobile application is installed, I need to be directed to the verification screen in the mobile application. How can I do it?

Comment: You need to do deeplinking inside your mobile application here is the link for the same

https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking